# "Not a valid password" error when reflecting an encrypted Access database

Tags: python, ms-access, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-access

i'm beginner in sqlalchemy, i want to reflect my table in database to object, but always return invalid password, even though the password is correct. I dont understand why this happend. When i try to inspect they return my table name, so my password, connection string or on create_engine is correct.
when my *database have no password* is fine i can reflect it to Object, that's so weird.
but why when i reflect *database with password* it's error, always return "Not a valid password" ??,

[My MS. Access Tbl 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LW2v.png)

[My MS. Access Tbl 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nswmj.png)

[Error in Reflect but My Table name is returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QchGP.png)

[This is my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iJYF.png)

because I was curious I also made a test select data, and it turned out to be successful in retrieving the data

[it's returned my data and success created connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jttwO.png)

[when i add some code for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Zbe.png)

I think all it's correct but why cannot reflect??, Please Help.

[My Reference connection_string](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/Getting-Connected#connecting-with-an-odbc-connection-string)

[My Reference SqlAlchemy Automap Reflect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html#basic-use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just released sqlalchemy-access version 1.1.1 to address this issue. Note that as described in [Getting Connected](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/Getting-Connected#encrypted-database-database-level-password-1) if you want to use a pass-through ODBC connection string with an encrypted database you need to supply the password in two places:

```py
driver = "{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}"
db_path = r"C:\Users\Public\test\sqlalchemy-access\gord_test.accdb"
pwd = "tiger"
connection_string = (
    f"DRIVER={driver};"
    f"DBQ={db_path};"
    f"PWD={pwd};"
    f"ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;"
)
connection_uri = (
    f"access+pyodbc://admin:{pwd}@/"
    f"?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}"
)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri)
```

Comment: hi, thank you for comment, and thank you for fix the issue, i have update it and now it's work.. Thanks.